# If a matrix has multiple left inverse, then solution is not unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to clarify the statement " If A has a left inverse, Ax=b has a unique solution."
This is saying that A only has at most one left inverse correct? Because if A has more than one left inverse then x would not be unique since if Y1 and Y2 and left inverse of A, x=Y1b and Y2b are both solutions.

Comment: I think you are confusing left inverses with right inverses. How, if $Y$ is a left-inverse of $A$, $x=Yb$ is a solution of $Ax=b$? $A(Yb) = b$ only if $AY=I$, that is, $Y$ is a right-inverse of $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible but left-invertible, it has infinitely many left-inverses.

Comment: well assume Y is a left tinverse, then multiply both sides by Y and we get x=Yb,

Comment: @william: does your textbook require $A$ to be a square matrix? If so, then having a left inverse is equivalent to $A$ being invertible and therefore the equation $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ has a unique solution.

Comment: @William And so? It does not follow from $Y_1b = Y_2b$ that $Y_1=Y_2$. However, the restrictions of all left-inverses to the image of $A$ are equal.

Comment: @amsmath, yes . I'm saying that since Y1b does not equal Y2b, then that means having multiple left inverse means Ax=b has multiple solutions.

Comment: @amsmath what does restriction left inverse to the image mean?

Comment: Since it is possible for there to be two *different* matrices $\ Y_1\ $ and $\ Y_2\ $ such that $\ Y_1b=Y_2b\ $, your conclusion is unwarranted. This will be true if each row of $\ Y_2\ $ is the sum of the corresponding row of $\ Y_1\ $ and a row vector orthogonal to $\ b\ $.

Comment: @William "I'm saying that since Y1b does not equal Y2b" Nobody said that. Of course, whenever $b$ is in the image of $A$ (i.e., $Ax = b$ for some $x$), for all left-inverses $Y$ you have $Yb = x$. But if $b$ is not in the image of $A$, then $Yb$ can be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: @azif00: It is not true that $(AY)b=b$ holds only if $AY=I$.

Comment: @William: **If** there is a solution, it is unique; but there may be no solution. If there is a solution, it will be $Bb$ where $B$ is a left inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ has a left inverse, then the linear transformation defined by $A$ is injective: because if $B$ is the left inverse, then from $Ax=Ay$ we can left multiply by $B$ to get $x=BAx=BAy = y$.

That means that $Ax=b$ has **at most** one solution; because if $x_0$ and $x_1$ are both solutions, then $b=Ax_0=Ax_1$, hence $x_0=x_1$.

However, the system $Ax=b$ could have **no** solutions. For example, the matrix
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
has left inverses (infinitely many, in fact): namely, all matrices of the form
$$B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & a\\
0 & 1 & b
\end{array}\right)$$
with $a,b$ arbitrary are left inverses of $A$.

For any $b$ of the form $(r,s,0)^T$, the system $Ax=b$ has exactly one solution; for $b$ of the form $(r,s,t)^T$ with $t\neq 0$, the system $Ax=b$ has *no* solutions.

You do not need the matrix to have a unique left inverse. In fact, a matrix has a unique left inverse if and only if it is a square matrix and has a two-sided inverse. Matrices that have more rows than columns may have left inverses (if they are of maximum rank) and when they do, they have multiple left inverses.

In summary: if $A$ is square, and it has a left inverse, then it is invertible, it has a unique left inverse, and $Ax=b$ has a unique solution for all $b$. If $A$ has more columns than row, then it never has a left inverse. If $A$ has more rows than columns but is not of maximum rank, then it has no left inverse. And if it has more rows than columns and is of maximum rank, then it has multiple left inverses, and the system $Ax=b$ has either no solutions or exactly one solution, and both situations will occur (since $A$ will not be surjective, so some choices of $b$ will yield a system with no solutions).

Comment: Hi arturo. The part that is making me confused is the fact that if A has more than one left inverse, Ax=b has more than one solution because for each inverse Yi, (YiA)x=Yib which equals x=Yib for each inverse Yi

Comment: @William: No, it does not have more than one solution; it has no solutions or a unique solution, because if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are (possibly different) solutions, then $Ax_1 = Ax_2$, and multiplying on the left by any inverse $Y_i$ you get $x_1=x_2$. You can have multiple matrices $Y_i$, but the products $Y_ib$ will all be the same. I gave you an **explicit** example above. Why don’t you try it? Take $b=(r,s,0)^T$, and see what happens when you multiply that $b$ by **any** of the matrices $B$. Do you really get different answers? Don’t just think about it: do the operations and check!

Comment: ok thats right, they are all the same. is there a way to prove this from a pure matrix point of view instead of linear transformation? I never learned that left inverse implies injectivity, only that left inverse implies existence of pivot in every column which implies full column rank.

Comment: @William: Are you reading what I wrote? Because it sure seems like you don’t. I wrote down a “matrix point of view” proof that if a solution exists then it is unique. I did it **twice**: once in the post, and again in the comment above. If you don’t want to read the answers, then why bother asking the question here in the first place?